# Iterate DAX expression over a range of dates (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, jira

I have the following measure in DAX:

```
Opened Tasks = 
    var date_n =  TODAY()
    return 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('issues'[idissue]), 
        FILTER(
            'issues',
            'issues'[creation_date] <= date_n 
            && ( 'issues'[closing_date] > dates_n || 
            'public incidencias'[status] <> "Closed")
        )
    )
```

Where **issues** is a table with Jira issues:

| idissue | creation_date | closing_date | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 10/01/2023 | 11/01/2023 | Closed |
| 103 | 10/01/2023 | None | Open |
| 1001 | 11/01/2023 | 20/01/2023 | Closed |
| 2002 | 20/01/2023 | 25/01/2023 | Closed |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

The purpose of this measure is to obtain the number of issues that were opened on a certain date. Thus, an issue is considered opened on a date 'n' if its creation_date is equal to or earlier than 'n,' and its closing_date is later than 'n' (or if its current status is different from "Closed").

The measure works fine for a individual date, but I need to apply it to a range of dates and getting as output a table similar to this:

| date | Opened Tasks |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 24 |
| 02/01/2022 | 35 |
| ... | ... |
| (today) | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

If you apply your measure to a table visual with a date column it works as expected.

Create a new table:
[Date Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF1LV.png)

```
Table = CALENDAR(DATE(2023,01,01),DATE(2023,12,31))
```

Be sure to define the relationship between the new Date table and your creation date in the 'issues' table.

It should produce this when the date column and measure are added to a table visual:
[Working Measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASOSI.png)

I was not sure from your question if this is your intended result or if you wanted a month by month snapshot of total opened tasks. If so, you can add a month column onto your new date table with:

```
Month = format('Table'[Date],"mmm")
```

to achieve this:
[Monthly opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrLvh.png)